# C# Repeater Object name not found in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Bit new at this but I have the following code snippet:

```cs
    if (objRecord.LicenseHistoryList !=null && objRecord.LicenseHistoryList.Length > 0 && txtLicenseOriginallyIssued.Text=="")
    {
        rptLicHistory.DataSource = objRecord.LicenseHistoryList;
        rptLicHistory.DataBind();
        foreach(RepeaterItem objItem in rptLicHistory.Items)
        {
            var objHistoryItem = objRecord.LicenseHistoryList[objItem.ItemIndex];
            ((TextBox)objItem.FindControl("txlicenseHistoryType")).Text = objHistoryItem.Type;
            ((TextBox)objItem.FindControl("txlicenseHistoryIssued")).Text = MVRDateToString(objHistoryItem.IssueDate);                
            if (objHistoryItem.EndorsementList != null && objHistoryItem.EndorsementList.Length > 0)
            {
                rptEndorseList.DataSource = objHistoryItem.EndorsementList;   //<=========== Error: CS0103: The name 'rptEndorseList' does not exist in the current context
                rptEndorseList.DataBind();
                foreach(RepeaterItem endorseItems in rptEndorseList.Items)
                {   
                    var objEndorseItem = objHistoryItem.EndorsementList[endorseItems.ItemIndex];
                    ((TextBox)objItem.FindControl("txtLicenseHistoryEndorement")).Text = objEndorseItem.EndorsementItem;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        divHistoryList.Visible = false;
        lblHistoryNoData.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```html
<div class="section">
    <h2>License and Permit History</h2>
    <div id="divHistoryList" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptLicHistory" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="display:flex;width: 100%;align-items: center;">
                    <div style="width:60px;">License:</div>
                    <div style="width:170px;"><asp:TextBox ID="txlicenseHistoryType" runat="server" style="border:none;"/></div>
                    <div style="width:50px">Issue:</div>
                    <div style="width:110px;"><asp:TextBox ID="txlicenseHistoryIssued" runat="server" style="border:none;"/></div>
                    <div style="width:50px;">Expire:</div>
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex;width: 100%;align-items: center;">
                    <div style="width:228px;"></div>
                    <div style="padding-right:5px;">Class:</div>
                    <div style="flex:1;"><asp:TextBox ID="txLicenseHistoryClass" runat="server" style="border:none"/>                            </div>
                </div>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptEndorseList" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLicenseHistoryEndorement" runat="server" style="border:none"/>                            </div>                                
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <SeparatorTemplate>
                        <div style="height: 30px;">&nbsp;</div>
                    </SeparatorTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SeparatorTemplate>
                <div style="height: 30px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblHistoryNoData" runat="server" data-en="<p>No License History Was Returned.</p>" data-es="" Visible="false" />
</div>
```

The code is used to read an XML file and I cannot figure out why I am not able to create this reader object `rptEndorseList`. The compiler complains that:

> CS0103: The name 'rptEndorseList' does not exist in the current context

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested repeater. And as "most" of your code shows, to get "things" inside of a repeater, then you have to use findcontrol. And that INCLUDES even a text box, lable, or in fact this "other" repeater!

So, you need this:

```
        ((TextBox)objItem.FindControl("txlicenseHistoryIssued")).Text = MVRDateToString(objHistoryItem.IssueDate);                
        if (objHistoryItem.EndorsementList != null && objHistoryItem.EndorsementList.Length > 0)
        {
            Repeater rptEnddorseList = (Repeater)objItem.FindControl("rptEndorseList);
            rptEndorseList.DataSource = objHistoryItem.EndorsementList;   //<=========== Error: CS0103: The name 'rptEndorseList' does not exist in the current context
            rptEndorseList.DataBind();
```

However, when I have a nested repeater, you probably better off to use the row data bind event of the FIRST (outer) repeater, and then during a data bind, you can deal with the ONE row of the repeater, including that of binding up the repeater that is nested for the one row.

So, then you data bind the first repeater, and then use that event.

So, then this:

```
    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
            e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {


            DataRowView rData = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            string HotelID = rData["ID"].ToString();
            string strSQL = $"SELECT * FROM People WHERE Hotel_ID = {HotelID}";

            Repeater rNested = e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2") as Repeater;
            rNested.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
            rNested.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

So say somthing like this:

```
    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
            e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

        var objHistoryItem = (LicentHistoryList)e.Item.DataItem;
        ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txlicenseHistoryType")).Text = objHistoryItem.Type;
        ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txlicenseHistoryIssued")).Text = MVRDateToString(objHistoryItem.IssueDate);
        if (objHistoryItem.EndorsementList != null && objHistoryItem.EndorsementList.Length > 0)
        {
            Repeater rptEndorseList =  ((Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptEndoresList"));
            rptEndorseList.DataSource = objHistoryItem.EndorsementList;   //<=========== Error: CS0103: The name 'rptEndorseList' does not exist in the current context
            rptEndorseList.DataBind();
        }
```

And if you going to process "rows" on the outer main repeater, then again I suggest using row data bound event of that repeater.

so, to grab any control in a given repeater row, you use FindControl, and that ALSO applies to a nested repeater control in that one row.

Now how you can use the e.Item.DataItem. Keep in mind that this repesents the WHOLE row used for the binding event, and you can even use columns that do NOT display in the ListView, GridView, or Repeater in this case.

However, that .DataItem DOES GO out of scope once the binding operations are complete. (so, unfortunately we can't use DataItem say for a repeater row click, since DataItem will now be null the instant the databinding operations are complete.

## Edit: The single row type returned is DataRowView

Hence:

```
    protected void rptLicHistory_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
            (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            DataRowView MyDataRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txLicenseHistoryType")).Text = MyDataRow["HotelName"].ToString();

            DataRowView HistoryItemRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

            ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txlicenseHistoryType")).Text = MyDataRow["column value here"].ToString();

            Repeater rptEndorseList = ((Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptEndoresList"));

            // here we get + load data for the child repeater.
            rptEndorseList.DataSource = ????
            rptEndorseList.DataBind();
        }
```

So, you now for that ONE row need to get the child data. It not clear how or where the data source for the child Repeater is to be obtatined, but that's what you need here.

So, I (unfortunately am wrong) had assumed that the full row "object" is avaiable during data bind. It is not ,but casted to a dataRowView. (in desktop land, the FULL object is available - so my mistake here).

So, at that point in code above, you need the child data, and it NOT at all clear if the child data is part of the object data set you bind? If it is, then you can use RowIndex, and you have to delcare that object at the form class level, so it's available during that data bind event.

Remember, I don't have your data objects here to test and play with, so this is like playing darts in a dark room.

But, the overall concept is simple:

For each main (outer repeater), the row data event fires, and we then are free to grab controls for that ONE row of the repeater. This includes grabbing the instance of the child Repeater, and THEN filling out the child rows - it just not clear where/what/how the child row are tucked away in your data object here.

Comment: Albert.  In attempting to try your method, I  get an error on the `var objHistoryItem = (LicenseHistoryList)e.Item.DataItem;` line stating that `namespace LicenseHistoryList could not be found`

Comment: I don't have your ojbects, so it's harder for me to see what is going on. Try using DataRowView, and see if that gets you all the columns of that single row in the binding event. You never show where you were running that code, but now you have a single binding event for the outer repeater, and the inner repeater is dealt with in the row data bound event. Give DataRowView Type a try as I did in the hotel repeater example.

Comment: Thanks.  I just removed that line of code but now e.Item.FindControl isn't working.  Banging my head because I can't find a tutorial on how to correctly do this.

Comment: My mistake, I thought on row item bind, you get a type of your object. you DO NOT, you get a type of DataRowView, so use data row view type here. See my edit.